# the result of the command mysql -u root -p -e "show slave status\G" | findstr "Last_SQL_Error" in JTextArea

Tags: java, mysql, database-replication

i want to avoid numbers that i specified in result.getString(38) and result.getString(37) here is the code:
i want another idea to extract last_SQL_Error and Last_SQLiErrno of show slave status

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
System.out.println("Driver O.K.");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
String user = "root";
String passwd = "";
Connection conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,passwd);
System.out.println("Connexion effective !");
Statement state=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet result=state.executeQuery("show slave status  ");

ResultSetMetaData resultMeta = result.getMetaData();
System.out.println("\n**********************************");
//On affiche le nom des colonnes
//for(int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++)
System.out.print("\t" +resultMeta.getColumnName(38).toUpperCase());
System.out.print("\t" +resultMeta.getColumnName(37).toUpperCase());
System.out.println("\n**********************************");
while(result.next()){
//for(int i = 1; i <= resultMeta.getColumnCount(); i++)
//System.out.print(result.getObject(i).toString());


    //String nom=result.getString(1);
    //String prenom=result.getString(2);
   jTextField2.setText(result.getString(37));

    jTextArea1.setText(result.getString(38));

}




} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();








    }
```

Comment: According to http://www.coderanch.com/t/302942/JDBC/databases/Check-status-MySQL-replication-JDBC you can simply execute `show slave status` as a statement using JDBC.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This should be an answer, not a comment, IMHO.

Comment: what do you mean ? i beg your pardon. i read what is in the link but its too different about my question

Comment: @Mureinik I don't have the time to verify if this is actually true, nor to put it in a good answer, so I leave a comment in the hope it is enough for the OP or that it triggers someone else to write an answer ;)

Comment: @user3448582 It is exactly your question. Use the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver to connect to the server, execute the query `show slave status` and process the resultset to look for `Last_SQL_Error`.

Comment: i used the connector/J but im trying to extract the Last_SQL_Error. i didnt find way to to it. how can i process the resultset? thank you

Comment: look at my code now i will edit it becaue i dont have possibility to post the code